# Detailed and specific use of Asp.net Sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session, memory, storage

Can any one help me in explaining the detailed and proper use of ASP.NET Sessions.

i read many web portals and blogs but i do not understand how to and where to use the sessions.

we create many sessions on page, for login, transfering some values from one page to another. but what is its impact on multiple users like more than 10000 users accessing the website, server transfer rate. memory storage, etc.

This may help many beginners, and also experienced person to properly use sessions in their project.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In case it helps, I answer your question in detail in my book. See my profile for info.

Comment: @RickNZ - I wish you give me a basic work-through and advantages and disadvantages of using sessions. If i was supposed to buy the book i would have not posted it as a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is roughly how it works:

When the user visits your webpage, a session ID is set in a cookie in the user's browser. Each time the browser sends a request to the server, the browser will pass the cookie containing the session ID to the server. This allows the server to recognize the user and associate data with the user across multiple page requests ([you can use sessions without cookies if you want to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)).

The server will by default store this data in memory. However, if multiple webservers are running the application and serving the same user, they will all need to know about the user's session data. Thus, you can configure your application to store session data using the "ASP.NET State Server" Windows service, or you can store the data in a SQL database (or you can write your own Session State Provider and store the data wherever you like). Moreover, storing the session data in memory is obviously a bad choice if you are worried your machine might crash (that obviously should worry you).

As for the "proper and detailed" use of ASP.NET sessions it is hard to say - it depends on what you are trying to achieve.
If you can help it, you should store only small amounts of data in sessions, as the combined sessions of all users visiting your website may take up quite a lot of space. Moreover, if you are using the ASP.NET State Server or the SQL Server session state stores the data you store needs to be serialized and deserialized, which will take a non-trivial amount of time for data of non-trivial size.

If what you are planning to store isn't confidential, an alternative approach might be to store the data in a cookie. That way your server will not have to worry about storing the data at all. This way you are trading memory (or disk space or whatever storage mechanism you choose) for bandwidth, as the cookie will now be part of the payload for every request.

Comment: waiting for more better answer, in case somebody publish in one or two days. otherwise i will accept it.

Comment: If you elaborate on what information you are missing, maybe I can help